# How to parametrize modules in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I mean a situation like this:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 1
#include <inttypes.h>
```

This exactly example is maybe of rare use, but it's just an example, and this method is used quite widely, especially inside projects. Macros defined for system or compiler type and version are taken up similar way, also macros defined in the compiler command line.

My question is whether there exists some mechanism to be used by the developer that is about to use the `import` declaration, when you already have a module using a normal name, something like this:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 1
#export __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
import std.inttypes;
```

Or, maybe even better - specify the parameters exported TO the module exclusively for it (that wouldn't spread to the others). Is there any mechanism that allows it to be achieved?

Comment: FYI: In this particular case, this parameterization would be pointless. `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` is for telling the header to declare some macros; `import`s of actual modules don't get to export macros. Only legacy module headers can.

Comment: @NicolBolas: my question wasn't about whether modules can see macros defined before importing them, but whether there is provided any feature that could be used to achieve a similar result.

Comment: You missed my point. Even if there was a feature, it wouldn't help *in this case*, because that particular "parameter" causes the header to generate macros. And you cannot `import` macros from an actual module.

Comment: But the above example doesn't `import` macros from the module - it declares a symbol that was intended to be seen and interpreted inside the module. If you are talking about particular macros provided by `inttypes.h`, that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I know that's beyond the scope of the question. That's why I made it a "For Your Information" comment instead of part of my answer. My point was simply that ***in this particular case***, it wouldn't accomplish anything, because the particular things changed by that macro would not be visible through a module import. So your specific example simply wouldn't be useful. That's all I was saying.

Answer (score 5):

About 80% of the entire point of modules is that a module is a *fixed* object, with its definitions being entirely unaffected by anything outside of the module itself. If you could "parameterize" them, that'd make them kind of worthless, since every time you import a module, you'd have to recompile it. Which is exactly the problem modules exist to prevent.

The only parameters modules take are command line arguments to the compiler, just like any other translation unit.

Comment: I don't understand why parametrization would have to be "impossible". First of all, the code inside the module must have access to macros defined by the compiler in order to provide system or compiler-dependent part of the code, otherwise this feature is not going to be adopted almost at all.

Comment: Example: we have a wrapper for encryption library, which's implementation can be provided for openssl, gnutls and mbedtls, which one, is defined at compile time. How can we make use of modules if we can't have them with conditional compiling?

Comment: "*How can we make use of modules if we can't have them with conditional compiling?*" The last sentence tells you how: you use command line arguments. What you're not allowed to do with modules is compile one part of a program under different rules from another part.

Comment: That's very good, of course, but if I, for example, provide a parameter for `import` of particular module, this will be also required to be imported with the same parameters in the whole program.

Ok, this actually answers more-less the question, although some kind of disappointing way :)

Comment: "_the code inside the module must have access to macros defined_"; yes it does. But that's when you're compiling the module, not when you're `import`-ing it.

Comment: @Ethouris: For a small number of variants, there’s nothing stopping you from creating a number of modules that share (most of) their code using the usual preprocessor mechanisms.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that's exactly what I wanted to avoid. Modules have been predicted as a solution that should allow me to keep all code that touches upon its purpose in a single file - even if this isn't the only supported way.

Comment: @Ethouris: It's also a solution that keeps you from recompiling stuff. You can't have it both ways. If keeping all code in a single file requires compiling at the point of importation, then you can't use a system that's designed to *prevent* compiling at the point of importation. And even from a logical perspective, a module is a sequence of definitions. If you need to import different sets of definitions at different times, then by definition you are not importing the same module.

Comment: I understand, but issues that cause compiling different ways depending on either system properties or wishes of the user specified at build configure time still do exist. I'm not expecting the module system to support them, but it could at least not make people's life harder, or worseover to force them stay with bare `#include` in these cases.

Comment: Example: the module system wants to prevent users from using a module and an include file using different set of configuration macros. So, if you compile a module with different flags and macros than it results from the command line you use now, it should simply fail, informing you that module must be recompiled for that flag set.

Comment: @Ethouris: "*I understand, but issues that cause compiling different ways depending on either system properties or wishes of the user specified at build configure time still do exist.*" And modules support that; you can provide appropriate command line arguments and so forth. What they *don't* support is *include-time* nonsense like in your example, where multiple different files could include "the same" module that is actually different stuff because of some definitions made above the module include location.

Comment: Can't exactly agree. The "include-time nonsense" might not exist when you specify some parameters for `import` instruction, as well as the parameter specification is a part of the `import` specification - so trying to link together parts that import the same module with different parameters can be easily detected - in contradiction to `#include` method, and unfortunately also in contradiction to parametrizing modules through command-line macros.

Comment: Real life example: [SRT](https://github.com/Haivision/srt) may be configured at build time to work with openssl, gnutls or mbedtls, or also no encryption support. Let's say, I'd like to provide SRT as a module, and the app developer chooses to use mbedtls. Should I state that "SRT with mbedtls" and "SRT with openssl" are two different modules?

Comment: @Ethouris: "*Should I state that "SRT with mbedtls" and "SRT with openssl" are two different modules?*" That all depends on how you want to present these different pieces of code. And whether you want to allow the same application to use "SRT with mbedtls" and "SRT with openssl".

Comment: @Ethouris: "*so trying to link together parts that import the same module with different parameters can be easily detected*" It's also detectable with modules, where the "module recipe" (as command line parameters are called) is something that the build system has to be aware of and understand conflicts within.

Comment: (1). So, an application must decide which of SSL libraries it wants to use. When compiled into a shared library, this library is bound to a specific SSL library. How can I then make one module out of it - or, I need to decide things at compile time so the SSL library is bound to the module (that is, "separate modules" as I said)?

Comment: (2) No, detection as to whether a module has been compiled with different flags and macros is same easily detectable as today without modules. Modules have a chance to have it, as they have a dedicated ABI so they potentially may contain various variants of the code. Of course, they can't be compiled with all variants in when they are solved by macros (as PP must be passed through anyway), but with some top-level constants that select which functions to use depending on a parameter, I don't see why not.

Comment: After some time I read this again and I came to a conclusion: This can be solved by using module partitions, while the whole module would provide nothing by itself, only partitions would provide the solution and of course this will provide all variants as required. The question is: can different partitions be generated out of the same code and can there be dependencies defined for various combinations? As example for above: `import srt:enc_none; import srt:core` could select SRT with no encryption, though any encryption spec is necessary...?

Answer (score 1):

If you're the one writing the module, you can use templates and specialization to configure/parameterize it.  Consider the following:

```cpp
//=====================================
// Module
//=====================================
template<typename EnableIf = void>
struct FooConfig {
    static constexpr int value = -1;
};

template<typename Config = FooConfig<> >
void foo() {
  // Some functionality based on the configuration settings.
  std::cout << Config::value << std::endl;
}

//=====================================
// Module configuration
// (lives outside module)
//=====================================
template<>
struct FooConfig<void> {
  static constexpr int value = 2;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/df5185cP4

Unlike with macros, the "parameterization" happens *after* import.  The module itself is fixed - though you can specialize things within it, including other template functions to enable whatever custom behavior you want.

So, following the discussion in one of the other answers, you could put in all the implementations for different encryption libraries (assuming they are all available on the system building the module) and use a configuration parameter to select between them.

Or probably more practically, you would have your base library provide an interface for encryption (with a default of none), then have a *separate* module provide the implementation, and use either a configuration parameter or other template specialization mechanisms to pick up that implementation.